# Ubuntu Night Light sunset time incorrect

Tags: display, location, night-light

I'm running 18.04. I have the night light set to run from sunset to sunrise. However, it's been turning on early, multiple hours before sunset and is already to maximum redness before the sun even starts setting. Perhaps it's a bug that mishandles the daylight savings time shift? I don't think it used to be this bad before the time change. (I'm on PDT.) I've checked the time settings, it's all correct.

Anyone run into a similar issue? Any fixes (aside from just manually setting the night light times myself)?

Comment: If you click on Manual, does it not give the sunset and sunrise figures? In my case (CET) 20:00 to 06:00 by default and https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=sunrise+sunset+CET&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 shows it to be about right.

Comment: This link might also be of use: https://vitux.com/how-to-change-the-timezone-on-your-ubuntu-system/

Comment: Enable location services (In Privacy settings) just long enough for Night Light to get your position.

Comment: I think enabling location services fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To compute sunrise and sunset times, your system needs to know your location. Enable location services in privacy settings. When the times are correct you can disable location services.

Answer (score 1):

If it' s one hour, it is intended as https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/125 suggests that they want a "gradual" change.  If it's multiple hours, it is another problem.